# Amazon AWS suspend account website sill available

Tags: amazon-web-services

Today I closed my AWS account. Amazon send me email which contained This e-mail confirms that you have closed your Amazon Web Services account and cancelled your access to all AWS Service Offerings. But my website is sill available, why?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming; it is a question about a commercial web site service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When AWS cancels you account it takes some time for them to get rid of all resources. So wait for some time.

Read more here

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/close-aws-account/